# GraphQL fragments in Vue

Tags: typescript, vue.js, graphql, vuex, vue-mixin

Before describing a problem and the question, based on this problem, I need to say, that it is architectural problem firstly and I've searched an answer or something like it many times with different keywords, but always got guides and articles like "Your first GraphQL app with Vue and Typescript". Seems like I have a more complex question, that requires more complex way to answer, and I believe, that by asking it there I can receive at least a first minimal clue of answer, that I need.

Also I'm very apologize, if I duplicated or asked the question, that had been answered before. Basic search through stackoverflow gave me no results.

So, let's say we have a GraphQL schema, that contains following types

```
type Company {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  code: String
  address: Address
}

type Address {
  id: ID!
  city: String!
  # here might be many other fields, but provided ones are enough to ask
}
```

We also have query in schema

```
type Query {
  companies (input: FindCompaniesInput!): [Company!]!
}
```

And its frontend wrapper

```
query Company ($input: FindCompaniesInput!, $withAddress: Boolean, $withCode: Boolean) {
  companies(input) {
    ...CompanyItem
    code @include(if: $withCode)
    address @include(if: $withAddress) {
      id
      city
    }
  }
}
```

And query *input* type looks like this

```
type FindCompaniesInput {
  ids: [ID!]
  take: Int
  offset: Int
  nameLike: String
  cityLike: String
}
```

In 7 different Vue components I need to load one of 4 fragments, based on type `Company` using query `companies`. For example, for dropdown input component, I need this

```
fragment CompanyItem on Company {
  id
  name
}
```

but for company card component I need

```
fragment CompanyCard on Company {
  id
  name
  address {
    city
  }
}
```

and so on.

Now, about Vue app. I use Vue with Typescript, and related packages, such as `vue-class-component` and `vue-property-decorator`. For generating types from schema, I use `apollo-graphql`. I designed the app without storing graphql entity objects in Vuex. I use mixins for that purpose. I understand, that use of pattern, based on mixins is risky, but I minimized risks (or I think that I did that) using following approach

I declare *mixin contexts*

```
import { CompanyItem } from '@/api/graphql/generated/fragments'

type CompanyMixinContext = {
  items: CompanyItem
  isPageLoading: boolean
}


@Component
export class CompanyMixin extends Vue {
  // I swap place of 'mixin' suffix in name, to easily access it in vue-dev-tools
  // component properties are sorted, so all inherited mixins display grouped
  protected mixinCompany: CompanyMixinContext = {
    items: null
    isPageLoading: false
  }

  protected async queryCompaniesPage(input: FindCompaniesInput) {
    // ...here I query companies chunk and wrap it in try/catch/finally
  }
}
```

And then, when it needs, I extend my component with mixin.

```
<script lang="ts">
// omit imports...

@Component
export default MyComponent extends CompanyItemMixin {
  // To use mixin context in template I declare a getter,
  // omitting in its name a 'mixin' suffix
  private get company () { return this.mixinCompany } 

  // The rest code of the component...
}
</script>
```

Finally, when I showed a code, that in use now in my app, I can now ask a question.

Is there a way to use single query with parameters for entity, even without mixins, but with reusable vue+typescript code, that able to return proper type based on variables?

I don't want to write 7 functions, or, in my case 7 mixins, that have 99% identic code and work with same GQL entity but still differs in types they working with.

p.s. The main feature of using GraphQL is that you can query different entity structure in different ways, but how can I reduce similar code to handle query and work with it using some universal approach (vuex/mixins) is still a mystery for me. I'm sure there are a lot of high-quality frontend engineers, who can answer that, I'll start here in search for it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know enough about mixins to your specific question, but you may want to look at existing libraries like [Vue Apollo](https://apollo.vuejs.org) that already provide the sort of functionality you're trying to implement.